# strange JavaScript sorting bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

So I came across this weird sorting bug in JS when this sequence is sorted:

```
console.log([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 9].sort());
```

which outputs

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 9]
```

so I tried a few other cases where the last 9 was 0 - 8. The sorting works as expected for both 0 and 1, but for numbers between 2 - 9, the sequence is not sorted.

```
[0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 5]
```

Behavior is same on Firefox and Chrome

I didn't know where else to go so I though I'd share here.

Test: https://jsbin.com/lixasowubi/edit?js,console

Comment: It's explained in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort), the relevant part is [*§22.1.3.25.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-sortcompare) steps 5 and 6: *Let xString be ? ToString(x)*, i.e. by default the values are sorted as strings, regardless of their Type in the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.
>
> This works well for strings ("Apple" comes before "Banana"). However,
>   if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because
>   "2" is bigger than "1".

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

To sort as numbers please use

```
.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b }) // Ascending
.sort(function(a, b) {return b - a }) // Descending
```

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. This should have been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript sorts alphabetically. This means that "10" is lower than "5", because "1" is lower than "5".

To sort numerical values you need to pass in numerical comparator like this:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;  // any negative number works
  if (a > b) return 1;   // any positive number works
  return 0; // equal values MUST yield zero
}

[1,10, 5].sort(sorter);
Or you can cheat by passing simpler function:

function sorter(a, b){
  return a - b;
}

[1, 10, 5].sort(sorter);
```

Logic behind this shorter function is that comparator must return x>0 if a > b, x<0 if a < b and  zero if a is equal to b. So in case you have

a=1 b=5
a-b will yield negative(-4) number meaning b is larger than a

a=5 b=1
a-b will yield positive number(4) meaning a is larger than b

a=3 b=3
a-b will yield 0 meaning they are equal